# PHP Dynamic Links issues - need explanation

Tags: php

First I would like to say that I am new in php.

I am creating a php website for a fictional music store. I have created a database and I have insert all my information to the website from the database using php. In my project I have three links which are “Home, About Us, Contact Us”. I have insert those three links in my website using this code

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET["id"];
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT id,menu_title,target FROM menu_titles");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$id = $result["id"];
$title = $result["menu_title"];
$target = $result["target"];
echo "<li><a href='index.php?id=$id&title=$title&target=$target'>$title</a></li>";
}
?>
```

The code above will loop through my database and get the links.

My table in my database have 3 columns which are “id, menu_title, target”.

I have added the “target” column in order to use it with $_GET so it will show me different content.

In addition, I have created about_us.php file so it will take the user to that page when pressing the “About Us” link.

My question is how can I change the links of my website in order to show the content about that specific link? For example “Home” show index.php “About Us” shows only about_us.php content and “Contact Us” show contact_us.php content

Index.php is working fine, the problem I have is with the other links content.

Please explain me how I can get my links working and open the about_us.php file when the link About Us is pressed and same thing for Contact Us.

Thanks.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
include ("includes/layouts/header.php");
include ("includes/database/db.php");
$id = $_GET["id"];
$target = $_GET["target"];
?>
<!-- START OF THE MAIN SLIDER -->
<div class='container-fluid col-xs-12'>
<div class='carousel_bg'>
<div id='carousel' class='owl-carousel owl-theme'>
<img src='images/slideshow_imgs/adele_slideshow.jpg' alt='adele_photo'>
<img src='images/slideshow_imgs/multiple_covers_slideshow.jpg' alt='multiple_music_covers_photo'>
<img src='images/slideshow_imgs/oranged_up_slideshow.jpg' alt='oranged_up_photo'>
<img src='images/slideshow_imgs/random_covers_slideshow.jpg' alt='random_music_covers'>
<img src='images/slideshow_imgs/sean_tizzle_slideshow.jpg' alt='sean_tizzle_photo'>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END OF MAIN SLIDER -->

<!-- MAIN SECTIONS STARTS -->
<!-- TOP SECTION STARTS HERE -->

<section>
<div class='container dark_grey_color cont_space'>
<div class='row dark_grey'>
<div class='title'>
<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT id,title FROM sections_titles WHERE id  = 1");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if (isset($_GET["id"]))
$id = $result["id"];
$title = $result["title"];
echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
?>
</div> 
<div class='devider'>
</div>
</div>


<div class='row'>
<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM top_albums_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$album_name = $result["album_name"]; 
$img = $result["image"]; 
$artist = $result["artist"]; 
$company = $result["company"]; 
$genre = $result["genre"]; 
$price = $result["price"]; 
$buy = $result["buy_now"]; 
$id = $result["id"]; 
echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
<a href ='index.php?id=$id&artist=$artist&company=$company&genre=$genre&price=$price' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'>
<div class='inside_box'>
<div class='small_title'>
<h4>$album_name</h4>
</div>
<div class='photo_box'>
<img src=$img class='img_dim'>
</div>
<div class='info'>
<p>Artist: $artist</p>
<p>Company: $company</p>
<p>Genre: $genre</p>
<p>Price: $$price</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class='buy_now'>
<p>$buy</p></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>";
}
?>
</div>
</div>
<!-- TOP SECTION END HERE -->

<!-- MIDDLE SECTION STARTS HERE -->

<div class='container light_grey_color cont_space'>
<div class='row dark_grey'>
<div class='title'>
<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT id,title FROM sections_titles WHERE id  = 2");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if (isset($_GET["id"]))
$id = $result["id"];
$title = $result["title"];
echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
?>
</div>
<div class='devider'>
</div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM middle_albums_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$album_name = $result["album_name"]; 
$img = $result["image"]; 
$artist = $result["artist"]; 
$company = $result["company"]; 
$genre = $result["genre"]; 
$price = $result["price"]; 
$buy = $result["buy_now"];
$id = $result["id"];
echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
<a href ='index.php?id=$id&artist=$artist&company=$company&genre=$genre&price=$price' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'>
<div class='inside_box'>
<div class='small_title'>
<h4>$album_name</h4>
</div>
<div class='photo_box'>
<img src=$img class='img_dim'>
</div>
<div class='info'>
<p>Artist: $artist</p>
<p>Company: $company</p>
<p>Genre: $genre</p>
<p>Price: $$price</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class='buy_now'>
<p>$buy</p></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>";
}
?>

</div>
<!-- end of row -->
</div>
<!-- END OF MIDDLE SECTION CONTAINER -->

<!-- BOTTOM SECTION STARTS HERE -->
<div class='container dark_grey_color cont_space'>
<div class='row dark_grey'>
<div class='title'>
<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT id,title FROM sections_titles WHERE id  = 3");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if (isset($_GET["id"]))
$id = $result["id"];
$title = $result["title"];
echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
?>
</div>
<div class='devider'>
</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>


<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM bottom_albums_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$album_name = $result["album_name"]; 
$img = $result["image"]; 
$artist = $result["artist"]; 
$company = $result["company"]; 
$genre = $result["genre"]; 
$price = $result["price"]; 
$buy = $result["buy_now"];
$id = $result["id"];    
echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
<a href ='index.php?id=$id&artist=$artist&company=$company&genre=$genre&price=$price' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'>
<div class='inside_box'>
<div class='small_title'>
<h4>$album_name</h4>
</div>
<div class='photo_box'>
<img src=$img class='img_dim'>
</div>
<div class='info'>
<p>Artist: $artist</p>
<p>Company: $company</p>
<p>Genre: $genre</p>
<p>Price: $$price</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class='buy_now'>
<p>$buy</p></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>";
}
?>
</div>
<!-- end of row -->
</div>

<!-- SMALL SLIDER STARTS HERE -->

<div class='container'>
<div class='carousel_bg'>
<div class='row thumbs'>
<div class='title'>
<h3>UPCOMING SONGS</h3>
</div>
<div class='devider'>
</div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>
<div class='col-md-10'>
<div id='carousel_thumb' class='owl-carousel owl-theme'>
<img src='images/slideshow_small_imgs/bob_marley.jpg' alt='bob_marley_photo'>
<img src='images/slideshow_small_imgs/coldplay.jpg' alt='coldplay_photo'>
<img src='images/slideshow_small_imgs/music_covers.jpg' alt='random_covers'>
<img src='images/slideshow_small_imgs/the_neverclaim.jpg' alt='the_neverclaim_photo'>
<img src='images/slideshow_small_imgs/twenty_one_pilots.jpg' alt='twenty_one_pilots_photo'>
</div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END OF SMALL SLIDER CONTAINER -->
<!-- SMALL SLIDER STARTS HERE -->
</section>
<?php
include ("includes/layouts/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Look at this [page](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) They have given some example.

Comment: *"Index.php is working fine"* -- not really. You have a bunch of problems: the [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) PHP extension is deprecated since PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7.0; use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead; `$_GET["id"]` is not used (in the posted code); it is assigned to variable `$id` but it's never used (the value of `$id` is overwritten); because the ampersand (`&`) is a special character in HTML you need to encode it (`&amp;`) everywhere in HTML (`&amp;title=`).

Comment: $_GET["id"]; what value store ?

Comment: Yes about the mysql i know im using an old version i will update it to mysqli before finishing my project. As for the $id i am using it in order to get th id of the title.

Comment: You probably want to use a query like `SELECT id,menu_title,target FROM menu_titles WHERE id=$id` right?

Comment: he's using a loop to display all the links, that would just display one link on his nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `include` the file of the page you are wanting inside `index.php`.

This will embed the contents of `$target.php` wherever you choose within `index.php`. I recommend placing this below the `while()` loop which generated your links.

```
if($target == "index"){
    //dont include a page here as you're already in index and you don't want the page to include itsself.
} else {

     include($target.".php");
}
```

It is also worth noting some things mentioned in the comments in your question by [axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac).

1. The mysql_ extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and removed as of PHP 7.0. Changing extensions is simple and you should use either one of these links to the documentation. [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)  OR  [PDO mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).
2. `$id` and `$id = $_GET["id"];` is redundant in your code. You are only using the `$title` and `$target` attributes of your database table rows.

EDIT: Specific to your index page you need to move the `content` of `index.php` to another file perhaps `indexcontent.php`. This keeps the main content separate from the statis parts of your page like the navigation, and content 'area'.

Alternatively you could keep the content inside `index.php` and wrap the if statement around the content which I separated below.

You would then have the following:

`index.php`

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
include ("includes/layouts/header.php");
include ("includes/database/db.php");
$id = $_GET["id"];
$target = $_GET["target"];
?>
<!-- START OF THE MAIN SLIDER -->
<div class='container-fluid col-xs-12'>
<div class='carousel_bg'>
<div id='carousel' class='owl-carousel owl-theme'>
<img src='images/slideshow_imgs/adele_slideshow.jpg' alt='adele_photo'>
<img src='images/slideshow_imgs/multiple_covers_slideshow.jpg' alt='multiple_music_covers_photo'>
<img src='images/slideshow_imgs/oranged_up_slideshow.jpg' alt='oranged_up_photo'>
<img src='images/slideshow_imgs/random_covers_slideshow.jpg' alt='random_music_covers'>
<img src='images/slideshow_imgs/sean_tizzle_slideshow.jpg' alt='sean_tizzle_photo'>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END OF MAIN SLIDER -->


<?php
if($target == "index"){

    include("indexcontent.php");

} else {

     include($target.".php");
}
?>



<?php
include ("includes/layouts/footer.php");
?>
```

and

`indexconent.php`

```
<!-- MAIN SECTIONS STARTS -->
<!-- TOP SECTION STARTS HERE -->
<section>
<div class='container dark_grey_color cont_space'>
<div class='row dark_grey'>
<div class='title'>
<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT id,title FROM sections_titles WHERE id  = 1");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if (isset($_GET["id"]))
$id = $result["id"];
$title = $result["title"];
echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
?>
</div> 
<div class='devider'>
</div>
</div>


<div class='row'>
<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM top_albums_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$album_name = $result["album_name"]; 
$img = $result["image"]; 
$artist = $result["artist"]; 
$company = $result["company"]; 
$genre = $result["genre"]; 
$price = $result["price"]; 
$buy = $result["buy_now"]; 
$id = $result["id"]; 
echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
<a href ='index.php?id=$id&artist=$artist&company=$company&genre=$genre&price=$price' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'>
<div class='inside_box'>
<div class='small_title'>
<h4>$album_name</h4>
</div>
<div class='photo_box'>
<img src=$img class='img_dim'>
</div>
<div class='info'>
<p>Artist: $artist</p>
<p>Company: $company</p>
<p>Genre: $genre</p>
<p>Price: $$price</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class='buy_now'>
<p>$buy</p></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>";
}
?>
</div>
</div>
<!-- TOP SECTION END HERE -->

<!-- MIDDLE SECTION STARTS HERE -->

<div class='container light_grey_color cont_space'>
<div class='row dark_grey'>
<div class='title'>
<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT id,title FROM sections_titles WHERE id  = 2");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if (isset($_GET["id"]))
$id = $result["id"];
$title = $result["title"];
echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
?>
</div>
<div class='devider'>
</div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM middle_albums_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$album_name = $result["album_name"]; 
$img = $result["image"]; 
$artist = $result["artist"]; 
$company = $result["company"]; 
$genre = $result["genre"]; 
$price = $result["price"]; 
$buy = $result["buy_now"];
$id = $result["id"];
echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
<a href ='index.php?id=$id&artist=$artist&company=$company&genre=$genre&price=$price' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'>
<div class='inside_box'>
<div class='small_title'>
<h4>$album_name</h4>
</div>
<div class='photo_box'>
<img src=$img class='img_dim'>
</div>
<div class='info'>
<p>Artist: $artist</p>
<p>Company: $company</p>
<p>Genre: $genre</p>
<p>Price: $$price</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class='buy_now'>
<p>$buy</p></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>";
}
?>

</div>
<!-- end of row -->
</div>
<!-- END OF MIDDLE SECTION CONTAINER -->

<!-- BOTTOM SECTION STARTS HERE -->
<div class='container dark_grey_color cont_space'>
<div class='row dark_grey'>
<div class='title'>
<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT id,title FROM sections_titles WHERE id  = 3");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if (isset($_GET["id"]))
$id = $result["id"];
$title = $result["title"];
echo "<h3>$title</h3>";
?>
</div>
<div class='devider'>
</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>


<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM bottom_albums_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$album_name = $result["album_name"]; 
$img = $result["image"]; 
$artist = $result["artist"]; 
$company = $result["company"]; 
$genre = $result["genre"]; 
$price = $result["price"]; 
$buy = $result["buy_now"];
$id = $result["id"];    
echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
<a href ='index.php?id=$id&artist=$artist&company=$company&genre=$genre&price=$price' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'>
<div class='inside_box'>
<div class='small_title'>
<h4>$album_name</h4>
</div>
<div class='photo_box'>
<img src=$img class='img_dim'>
</div>
<div class='info'>
<p>Artist: $artist</p>
<p>Company: $company</p>
<p>Genre: $genre</p>
<p>Price: $$price</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class='buy_now'>
<p>$buy</p></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>";
}
?>
</div>
<!-- end of row -->
</div>

<!-- SMALL SLIDER STARTS HERE -->

<div class='container'>
<div class='carousel_bg'>
<div class='row thumbs'>
<div class='title'>
<h3>UPCOMING SONGS</h3>
</div>
<div class='devider'>
</div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>
<div class='col-md-10'>
<div id='carousel_thumb' class='owl-carousel owl-theme'>
<img src='images/slideshow_small_imgs/bob_marley.jpg' alt='bob_marley_photo'>
<img src='images/slideshow_small_imgs/coldplay.jpg' alt='coldplay_photo'>
<img src='images/slideshow_small_imgs/music_covers.jpg' alt='random_covers'>
<img src='images/slideshow_small_imgs/the_neverclaim.jpg' alt='the_neverclaim_photo'>
<img src='images/slideshow_small_imgs/twenty_one_pilots.jpg' alt='twenty_one_pilots_photo'>
</div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END OF SMALL SLIDER CONTAINER -->
<!-- SMALL SLIDER STARTS HERE -->
</section>
```

Comment: if you put the lines at the bottom of your code then that should fix it

Comment: in my index.php i have included also a header.php at the top and a footer.php at the bottom... when u say to put the at the bottom u mean at the bottom of my index.php or footer.php?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the full code for index.php, it will help me understand better where you will want to include the contents.

Comment: which content on `index.php` do you `NOT` want to be displayed when the links are clicked?  I am assuming that the links are generated in `header.php`. and that you want everything below `<!-- MAIN SECTION>` and above `include('footer.php');` to disappear?

Comment: yes i want them to disappear and show the content of my about_us.php

Comment: No worries, and welcome to stack overflow. Please check the answer as accepted if it has solved your issue. You can do this by checking the tick below the up and down vote icons on the left pane. Make sure you check out [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get familarised with the site.